# Draw a circle on node in taxonomy or tree using tikz latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-trees

I am new to tikz and I want to add a circle on tree node but I didn't found any solution that how to draw a circle on node. If anyone has a suggestion or working example it will be a great favour.
Thanks
[image]

Comment: would you like to share your code which you have tried so far

Answer (score 2):

As starting point. By using `forest` for drawing tree:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,
               preview]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,
                shapes.callouts}

\begin{document}
{
\tikzset{
         node distance = 3mm,
    every label/.style = {circle, fill=blue, minimum size=2em, 
                          inner sep=0pt, anchor=center,
                          font=\small\sffamily, text=white},
             CO/.style = {ellipse callout, inner sep=1pt,
                          callout absolute pointer={#1},
                          callout pointer width=1.2 mm, callout pointer shorten=-1mm,
                          fill=black, font=\small\sffamily, text=white},
           Root/.style = {double, rounded corners, fill=cyan!30,
                          font=\small\sffamily\bfseries},
        }
    \begin{forest}
for tree={              
% style of tree nodes
  font=\sffamily\small,
  draw, semithick,
        align = center,
    inner sep = 2mm,
% style of tree (edges, distances, direction)
         edge = {draw, semithick, -stealth},
parent anchor = south,
 child anchor = north,
         grow = south,
forked edge,            
        l sep = 12mm,   % level distance
     fork sep = 6mm,    % distance from parent to branching point
        s sep = 4mm
            }
[Support for\\ visually impaired, 
 Root, name=root
  [AAA\\ aaaa,label=south east:5]
  [BB\\ bbbbb bbb\\ bb bbb b bbb,label=south east:114]
]
\node[CO=(root.north east),above right=of root] {159};
    \end{forest}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]